# x86 assembly on linux, movsd segfault

Tags: x86, segmentation-fault, shellcode

```
_start:
    jmp short call

shell:
    pop esi
    movsd ;move 4 byte from esi to edi (/bin)
    mov edx,edi ;edx contains /bin
    xor edi,edi 
    movsw ;move 2 bytes (/s) 
    xor ebx,ebx
    mov ebx,edi ;ebx contains /s
    xor eax,eax
    xor edi,edi
    movsb
    mov eax,edi ;eax contiene h
    mov esi,edx ;esi contains /bin

    xor ecx,ecx
    push ecx
    mov edx,esp ;edx dword NULL

    push ecx ;NULL
    push ecx ;NULL
    add esp,3 ;0
    push eax
    add esp,3 ;h
    push ebx
    add esp,2 ;/s
    push esi ;/bin  
    mov ecx,esp ;/bin/sh0,NULL

    xor edi,edi
    push edi
    add esp,3 ;0
    push eax
    add esp,3
    push ebx
    add esp,2
    push esi
    mov ebx,esp ;/bin/bash0

    xor eax,eax
    mov al,0xb
    int 0x80

call:
    call shell
    path db "/bin/sh"
```

i'm trying to write a shellcode (jmp-call-pop) that spawn a shell but i got a problem on the `movsd` instruction (segfault). I don't understand what is wrong, i setup esi with the ptr to the string so movsd should move 4 byte from esi to edi right? But why it is segfaulting?

Answer (score 2):

`movsd` moves 4 bytes from the memory pointed to by `esi` to the memory pointed to by `edi`.  You haven’t initialized `edi`, so this is a store to an arbitrary address; it’s not terribly surprising that it happens to segfault.

Intel’s Architecture Manual, Volume 2 (These are a free download and can answer all of your basic assembly questions.  Download them and familiarize yourself with where to find things if you’re going to be writing assembly):

> Moves the byte, word, or doubleword specified with the second operand
>   (source operand) to the location specified with the first operand
>   (destination operand). **Both the source and destination operands are
>   located in memory.**

Comment: `lea edi,[edx]` give me segfault! But i am initializing edi with the address of edx...am i right?

Comment: There is no such thing as the “address of `edx`”; `lea edi, [edx]` is equivalent to `mov edi, edx`, which doesn’t help because `edx` is also uninitialized.  You would do well to take some time to familiarize yourself with the basics of x86 assembly.

Comment: tell me if i am right: i cannot save the 4 byte of string directly to the register right? I have to use a buffer inside the .bss section...or not?

Comment: If you just want to get the memory pointed to by `esi` into a register, the correct way to do that is with a load (e.g. `mov edx, [esi]`).  Definitely download the Intel manuals though; reading them will be a lot faster than trying out every possible combination of instructions =)